# Delete table row using parent.removeChild(child)

Tags: javascript, function, delete-row, removechild

I have a table which starts off blank when a user opens the page and has rows added to it by the user. The user searches a DB and the results are echoed to a "Search results" table with the code below.

```
while ($dbsearch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query))
         {
            $dbu = $dbsearch['Username'];
            $id = $dbsearch['PlayerID'];
            $func = "add(" . $id . ", Brad Henry )";
         array_push ($_SESSION['players'],$dbsearch['PlayerID']);
         echo "<tr><td>".$id ."</td><td>".$dbu."</td><td><input type=\"submit\" id=\"PlayerAdded".$id."\" value=\"Add\" onclick=\"add('".$id."','".$dbu."');\"></input></td></tr>";
         }
```

This is working very well. When the user clicks add, the following function adds the search result to the "Todays event" table:

```
function add(id,name){
    var t = ("</td><td>");
    var str = ("<tr id='Players" + id + "'><td>")
    var ctr = ("</td></tr>")
    var place = ("<select name='place'><option value='17'>17th</option><option value='16'>16th</option><option value='15'>15th</option><option value='14'>14th</option><option value='13'>13th</option><option value='12'>12th</option><option value='11'>11th</option><option value='10'>10th</option><option value='9'>9th</option><option value='8'>8th</option><option value='7'>7th</option><option value='6'>6th</option><option value='5'>5th</option><option value='4'>4th</option><option value='3'>3rd</option><option value='2'>2nd</option><option value='1'>1st</option></select>")
    var points = ("<input name='points' placeholder='50'></input>");
    var cash = ("$<input name='cash' placeholder='0'></input>");
    var ticket = ("<select name='ticket'><option value='No'>No</option><option value='Yes'>Yes</option>");
    var del = ("<input type='submit' value='Delete' onclick='remove(" + id + ")'> </input>")

   $('#PlayerAdded').before(str+ id + t + name + t + place + t + points + t + cash + t + ticket + t + del + ctr);
}
```

My issue is that nothing happens when the Delete button (see var del) is clicked. `var del` calls the "Remove" function which is pasted below. I'm not sure where the error is and I have been searching online for an answer, but to no avail. I wonder if I am declaring `var child` incorrectly as it looks for an elementID with both a string and int...

```
function remove(RowID) {
    var parent = document.getElementById("resultTable");
    var child = document.getElementById("Players" + RowID);
    parent.removeChild(child);
}
```

Comment: Why not just `child.parentElement.removeChild(child);`?

Comment: There is no need to select parent element, you could do this using **element.parentNode.removeChild(element)**

Comment: @Jan that's great! Thank you, I'm new to JS and still have heaps to learn about it, I'm only starting to get my head around the DOM.. Thanks again. If you enter that as an answer I'll gladly tick it so you get the reputation points :D

Comment: I don't think it's an answer, we don't know what went wrong. But probably that the `id` of the table isn't really `resultTable` or that there's a `tbody` element between the `table` and the `tr`. And I commend you for trying to learn vanilla JavaScript, you really should do that first. But you might want to at least glance at a modern framework like Angular. And for DOM manipulation and element creation like this, documentFragments and `createElement` might be preferable.

Comment: You are correct on the `tbody` element. I guess my issue was that I was trying to skip straight from the `tr` to the `table` instead to `tr` to `tbody`.
Regardless, your line of code has fixed my issue very well. Thank you again. I intend to focus on learning more JS and Angular JS once I am done with this project.

Comment: Why are you placing your strings within (). They are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces invalid HTML markup. Remove items marked ** and add items marked ++. I've used the value 10 to be the id within your code.

```
<table>
      <tr id='Players10'>
   <td>10</td>
   <td></td>
   <td><select name='place'>
         <option value='17'>17th</option>
         <option value='16'>16th</option>
         <option value='15'>15th</option>
         <option value='14'>14th</option>
         <option value='13'>13th</option>
         <option value='12'>12th</option>
         <option value='11'>11th</option>
         <option value='10'>10th</option>
         <option value='9'>9th</option>
         <option value='8'>8th</option>
         <option value='7'>7th</option>
         <option value='6'>6th</option>
         <option value='5'>5th</option>
         <option value='4'>4th</option>
         <option value='3'>3rd</option>
         <option value='2'>2nd</option>
         <option value='1'>1st</option>
      </select></td>
   <td><input name='points' placeholder='50'>
      **</input>**</td>
   <td>$
      <input name='cash' placeholder='0'>
      **</input>**</td>
      <td>
      <select name='ticket'>
   <option value='No'>No</option>
   <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
++</select>++
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type='submit' value='Delete' onclick='remove(10)'>
      **</input>**
      </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Then test your code again.